# Using emplace for multimap, and constructors that take more than one argument

Tags: c++, c++11

I am having problems with emplace for multimap. I have this code:

```
std::multimap<int,Position> countries;
countries.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(someValue),
        std::forward_as_tuple(i,j,-1,-1,-1));

struct Position {
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    Position():a(-1),b(-1),c(-1),d(-1),e(-1){}
    Position(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e):a(a),b(b),c(c),d(d),e(e)
    {}
};
```

Position has constructor with 5 arguments as you can see. The very strange thing
that happens is that once I emplace all the elements, for whatever reason,
the -1 argument values I passed in the tuple are not set, and i and j are set properly,
that is the first two constructor arguments. Can you please suggest what could cause this?

Edit: This is what happens when emplace calls the constructor for Position. As you can see,
even though -1 is passed in emplace for the argument c, it has a wrong value in the constructor.

[image]

What is interesting is that if I replace the above code with:

```
std::forward_as_tuple(i,j,i,i,i)
```

then this problem goes away. The problem happens only if I pass directly an integer
value like 5 or -1 or whatever. Buy if I pass variables then it does not happen.

Here is the code that works. Instead of passing -1, I pass a variable called undefined.
For whatever reason it works.

```
  int undefined = -1;
  std::multimap<int,Position> countries;
  for (int i = 0; i < solution->getNumberOfRawSheets(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < solution->rawSheets[i].getNumberOfCountries(); j++) {
      countries.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(solution->rawSheets[i].countries[j].getUsedHeight()),
        std::forward_as_tuple(i,j,undefined,undefined,undefined));
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I can think of dozens of things that would cause this, limited mostly by my imagination.  Most or all of them are bugs in the code.  I think we need some more information to give you a useful answer.  For example, the definitions of `struct Position` and of `Position::Position(...)`.  Perhaps also the types of `i` and `j`.

Comment: I updated my post. The types are all int.

Comment: Another information I can give you is that when I debug and enter the Position constructor when it is called by emplace, the arguments are not passed correctly. Only the first two arguments are passed correctly.

Comment: Also, how do you know the values aren't set?  It could be that however you're testing the values that end up in the object is incomplete or otherwise subject to context.

Comment: I updated my topic to show you image. I debug, and I stop in the constructor to see what happens when emplace calls it.

Comment: Could you provide trivial executable example, showing this behavior?

Comment: @zch Ok I will write one in ideone.com

Comment: Information in a debug session is rather unreliable, especially if there are any optimizations enabled.  As a wild guess, it could be that the compiler is inlining the constructor and notices that the last three arguments are the same values that the default constructor would set, which it has already placed in the object in a preimage of some kind.  A much better way to test this behavior is by printing the values to `cout` --- a compiler is required to handle that completely because of the rules regarding side-effects.

Comment: ideone.com uses GCC 4.7.2, which doesn't have `emplace` for associative containers.

Comment: Ah yes I am failing at ideone.com. Can you recommend me where to run my example, I wrote it?

Comment: Kerrek SB that does not work actually.

Comment: Adam H. Peterson, actually even cout prints wrong values.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think that's true. `emplace` just forwards its arguments to the `std::pair` constructor, and `pair` doesn't have a constructor taking an arbitrary amount of parameters.

Comment: Here is another useful information. If I do this: std::forward_as_tuple(i,j,i,i,j)); then the values are passed ok. The problem happens if you pass directly integer values like 5 or -1 or whatever. If you pass variables it is ok. This is strange.

Comment: Add the example to the question.

Comment: @interjay: You're right. I'm not sure where I got that from, though I remember having puzzled over that in the past. Wishful thinking perhaps. Shame. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Too wishful I would say :)

Comment: You can test it online at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/. But it [works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=79d2e6decab9a878c4d34fd64e31cc67-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51)

Comment: Yes I created a small example also and it works fine for it. Strange...

Comment: I added new code at the bottom of my post to show the code that works. There is just one modification. I pass a variable called undefined, rather than directly the value of -1.

Comment: Run the example I posted on your compiler and see if it works. If it does, try to come up with a minimal example that fails, because the actual problem is probably not in the code you've shown.

Comment: @interjay I did and it works. I am not sure why this problem appears in my code.

Comment: This is why [self contained, compiling, correct examples](http://sscce.org/) are rather key when asking for help.  Your question did not even contain the actual problem with your code, as @interjay's sscce demonstrates.